# Print.PrintSupport.Source.dll Exception(1) Element Not Found Calling CDC::StartDoc

Tags: printing, mfc, visual-studio-2022

I'm hoping someone can help point me in the right direction here. I have a VS2008 application that I've been porting over to VS2022. It has been a mostly painless excercise. But printing crashes. Previews work fine but actual printing crashes in the CDC::StartDoc() call.

This code works just fine in the vs2008 code and hasn't been changed in the vs2022 code. I'm guessing I'm missing an include or library or something but don't know what I'm missing?

This is the debugger output:

> onecoreuap\printscan\print\workflow\printsupport\dll\printsupportutil.cpp(573)\Print.PrintSupport.Source.dll!7AC3BA60: (caller: 7AC26A2B) Exception(1) tid(7094) 80070490 Element not found.
> Exception thrown at 0x75A37402 in IPC2000.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x06B6E4AC.
> Exception thrown at 0x75A37402 in IPC2000.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x06B6DA50.
> Exception thrown at 0x75A37402 in IPC2000.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x0018BA70.
> Exception thrown at 0x75A37402 in IPC2000.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
> Print.PrintSupport.Source.dll!7AC19ED8: ReturnHr(1) tid(6770) 80070490 Element not found.
> Msg:[onecoreuap\printscan\print\workflow\printsupport\dll\printsupportutil.cpp(573)\Print.PrintSupport.Source.dll!7AC3BA60: (caller: 7AC26A2B) Exception(1) tid(6770) 80070490 Element not found.
> ]
> Print.PrintSupport.Source.dll!7AC151F7: LogHr(1) tid(6770) 80070490 Element not found.
> Exception thrown at 0x75A37402 (KernelBase.dll) in IPC2000.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80070490 : 'Element not found.'.
> Exception thrown at 0x75A37402 in IPC2000.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error at memory location 0x0018BBC8.

Comment: I finally found a clue on this after struggling for hours. It turns out that it is a permissions issue. The vs2008 version of the application was run AsAdministrator. With the vs2022 version, I'm moving to AsInvoker and working through getting rid of the assorted UAC issues we were getting. 

If I run the vs2022 application As Admin, it prints fine. Otherwise it crashes on CDC::StartDoc().

I'm going to go digging but if anyone has any ideas, I'd sure love to hear them.

Comment: If anyone's watching this. It looks like it might be a vs2022 environment thing. I just discovered that if I run the application from a shortcut, no matter the "run as administrator", the printing is fine. In the debugger, it looks like it gets this error no matter whether I run it As Admin or not. I tried running vs2022 as admin and setting the manifest to requiresAdmin and it still crashes in the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting this exact issue. It only happens while debugging in Visual Studio. If I run the application outside VS printing works fine.

My "fix" is to ignore that exception: while debugging in VS, go to Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings, expand "C++ Settings", and disable "winrt::hresult_error".

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in both VS2019 and VS2022 with existing code. The shipped product in VS2019 works, but a recompile does not. In VS2022, throws exception in CDC.StartDoc. Please update and I will do the same.