# GDI - Why the printing StartPage() function works in 32 bit but raises an exception in 64 bit?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, exception, printing, 64-bit

In Visual Studio 2019, I use the below code to print a jpeg image into a PDF document:

```cpp
// sdk
#include <string>
#include <memory>

// windows
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winspool.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Gdiplus.lib")

// resources
#include "Resource.h"

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HWND g_hWnd      = nullptr;
HWND g_hPrintBtn = nullptr;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void PrintToPDF();
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            return 0;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            // search for the pressed button
            if (g_hPrintBtn == reinterpret_cast<HWND>(lParam))
                PrintToPDF();

            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HWND CreateButton(const RECT& clientRect, const std::wstring& caption, LONG pos)
{
    // create button
    return ::CreateWindow(L"BUTTON",
                          caption.c_str(),
                          WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                          clientRect.left + 3,
                          clientRect.bottom - ((25 * pos) + 3),
                          (clientRect.right - clientRect.left) - 6,
                          25,
                          g_hWnd,
                          nullptr,
                          (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(g_hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
                          nullptr);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HBITMAP LoadJpgImage(const std::wstring& fileName)
{
    HBITMAP hBitmap = nullptr;

    // initialize GDI+
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR                    gdiplusToken;

    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, nullptr);

    // load the .jpg image
    std::unique_ptr<Gdiplus::Bitmap> pBitmap = std::make_unique<Gdiplus::Bitmap>(fileName.c_str());

    // check if the image is loaded successfully
    if (pBitmap->GetLastStatus() == Gdiplus::Ok)
    {
        Gdiplus::Status result = pBitmap->GetHBITMAP(Gdiplus::Color::Transparent, &hBitmap);

        // free resources
        pBitmap.reset();
    }
    else
        // error handling if image loading fails
        ::MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Failed to load image.", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

    // shutdown GDI+
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

    return hBitmap;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HDC GetPrinterDC(const std::wstring& printerName)
{
    HDC hDC = ::CreateDC(NULL, printerName.c_str(), NULL, NULL);

    if (!hDC)
        return nullptr;

    return hDC;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void PrintToPDF()
{
    HBITMAP hBitmap = LoadJpgImage(L"..\\PrintToPDF\\Resources\\Coffee.jpg");

    BITMAP bm;
    ::GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm);

    const std::size_t bmWidth  = bm.bmWidth;
    const std::size_t bmHeight = bm.bmHeight;

    HDC hDC = GetPrinterDC(L"Microsoft Print to PDF");

    const std::size_t cxPage = ::GetDeviceCaps(hDC, HORZRES);
    const std::size_t cyPage = ::GetDeviceCaps(hDC, VERTRES);

    ::DOCINFO di;
    di.cbSize      = sizeof(DOCINFO);
    di.lpszDocName = L"INVOICE TABLE : Printing...";
    di.lpszOutput  = L"..\\PrintToPDF\\Printed docs\\MyDoc.pdf";

    ::StartDoc(hDC, &di);
    ::StartPage(hDC);

    HDC hDcMem = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    ::SelectObject(hDcMem, hBitmap);

    ::BitBlt(hDC, (int)((cxPage - bmWidth) / 2), (int)((cyPage - bmHeight) / 2), 4032, 3024, hDcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    ::DeleteDC(hDcMem);

    ::EndPage(hDC);
    ::EndDoc(hDC);

    ::DeleteDC(hDC);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_     HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_     LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_     int       nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex  = {};
    MSG        msg   = {};
    BOOL       bQuit = FALSE;

    // register the window class
    wcex.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style         = CS_OWNDC;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wcex.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon         = ::LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPICON));
    wcex.hIconSm       = ::LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));
    wcex.hCursor       = ::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)::GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wcex.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"PrintToPDF";

    if (!::RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return 0;

    // create the main window
    g_hWnd = ::CreateWindowEx(0,
                              L"PrintToPDF",
                              L"Print to PDF",
                              WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                              CW_USEDEFAULT,
                              CW_USEDEFAULT,
                              800,
                              650,
                              NULL,
                              NULL,
                              hInstance,
                              NULL);

    ::ShowWindow(g_hWnd, nCmdShow);

    RECT clientRect;
    ::GetClientRect(g_hWnd, &clientRect);

    g_hPrintBtn = CreateButton(clientRect, L"Print to PDF", 1);

    // application main loop
    while (!bQuit)
    {
        // check for messages
        if (::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            // handle or dispatch messages
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                bQuit = TRUE;
            else
            {
                ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
                ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ::Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    // destroy the window explicitly
    ::DestroyWindow(g_hWnd);

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This above code works perfectly as long as I compile and execute it in 32 bit (x86). However the exact same code raises the below exception if I compile and execute it in 64 bit (x64):

[image]

As seen above, the exception happens while the ::StartDoc() function is executed. If I continue the execution (by pressing F5), the image is printed in the document, as expected, and no other error happen.

I cannot figure out why. Can someone point me what I'm doing wrong?

**-------- EDIT 1 --------**

It seems that it's a old known issue:

https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/issues/23850

[Print.PrintSupport.Source.dll Exception(1) Element Not Found Calling CDC::StartDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74747514/print-printsupport-source-dll-exception1-element-not-found-calling-cdcstartd)

Unfortunately these posts are quite old (more than 1 year). As it seems that this is a Visual Studio debugger issue instead of a real one, should I ignore this issue, or maybe someone know a solution?

Comment: It could be that you have not zeroed your `DOCINFO` structure so that the system is trying to work on invalid data in the `lpszDatatype` and `fwType` fields. I notice that you are writing direct to a file in he above code to create a .pdf file. However I do not think that will work as PDF files require to be encoded with specific metadata using a proper PDF printer driver, or library.

Comment: @OldBoy This is a relevant observation, I just tried to initialize my `DOCINFO` structure, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem. About the PDF, this is working for me, as I use the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer, which is provided by default since Windows 10. Of course it will not work on earlier Windows versions, or if the printer was uninstalled, but I'm aware about that.

Comment: I cannot suggest any other reason why that error could occur, and unless you can get something more from the debugger it is difficult to know what to investigate. I take your point on the print to PDF.